# How to open a popup textarea box asking user to submit comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have the following dropdown list as a part of my project:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select subject
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="rem"><a href="#">CS 520</a></li>
              <li class="rem"><a href="#">CS 530</a></li>
              <li class="rem"><a href="#">CS 571</a></li>
              <li class="rem"><a href="#">CS 575</a></li>

         </ul>
</div>
```

When i click on any of the *li*, i want to popup (not alert) a box containing textarea (to submit comments) and SUBMIT, CANCEL and RESET buttons.

I am unable to figure this out using JavaScript (or jQuery). Is there any way this can be achieved? I can find people giving examples where they do the similar problem with an alert, but I need to do it with a simple popup box.
There is somewhat similar problem's solution on this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/E9XVr/53/) ; But the JS code is too complex I guess. Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are using bootstrap...read their modal docs. They show you how to do it

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Check this and modify the code for list

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and correct accordingly, If will click on any *li* popup dialog will open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h3>Header</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <!-- content -->
            <ul data-role="listview" id="list">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Group 1</li>
                    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" data-id="1">List 1a</a></li>
                    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" data-id="2">List 1b</a></li>

                     <li data-role="list-divider">Group 2</li>
                    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" data-id="3">List 2a</a></li>
            </ul><!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- popup-menu -->
        <div data-role="popup" id="popup-menu">
            <ul data-role="listview" style="min-width:210px;">
                <li data-role="divider">Choose an action</li>
                    <li><a id="details" href="#">View details</a></li>
                    <li><a id="share" href="#">Share</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /popup-menu -->
    </div>

    <script>

    var currentId = 0;
    var baseURL = "person.php?id=";

    $('#page').on('pageinit', function(){
        $('#list li a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            currentId = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $("#popup-menu").popup("open", {transition:"slideup"} );
        });
    });

    $('#popup-menu').on('popupbeforeposition', function(){
        $("#details").attr("href", baseURL + currentId);
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more support and help , go through by giving this link in jsFidle [Click Here 1](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/5YKkM/) or check here [Link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/JRD06/sx0mjwe1/)
Check these links to open your popup and how it workd